# Can't seem to figure out the generate_password_hash function

Tags: python, flask, cs50, finance

I found the documentation for the generate_password_hash function online, but I keep getting an internal server error. can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?
Here's my code:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():

    if request.method == "POST":

        usertable = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("Must provide username")
        elif request.form.get("username") in usertable:
            return apology("Sorry, this username as already been taken")
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("Must provide password")
        elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("Must confirm password")

        uname = request.form.get("username")
        upassword = request.form.get("password")
        uconfirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        if uconfirmation != upassword:
            return apology("Confirmation password does not match")

        hashpassword = generate_password_hash(upassword, method = 'pbkdf2', salt_length = 8)

        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)", uname, hashpassword)

        return redirect ("/")

    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

Here's the error message: ValueError: [digital envelope routines] unsupported.

Comment: From Python version 3.10 onwards hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac. (used internally by werkzeugs generate_password_hash) is only available if Python is compiled with OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using bcrypt library. It's secure and reliable for hashing passwords and ensuring the utmost protection for sensitive data.

*Sign Up:*

```py
import bcrypt

password = "test"

salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), salt)

print(hash) # b'$2b$12$30FUkIAEzti77wTaKs8tFegxxAqTEUIAxsHCaUjsl3cFmJbpXnphe'
```

*Log In:*

```py
import bcrypt

password = "test"
hash = b'$2b$12$SUxuxWARWkyLpzPPLGUgXO7WMibuqvMNz.886snhKuNvtsBHOhS1C'

if not bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hash):
  print("Invalid password")
```